# Import Xcode project into another project without using Source Trees

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Referring to [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oj6_8zRfI4k) I want to import the `FastPdfKit` (which appears in the video) into a new single view project, so I can use any file I want, but without using the Source Tree method they followed in the video? Is there another method to do it?

PS. I actually do not understand why they used Source Trees to import their project into another one?

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want to include the whole source tree.. then you can make a static library of the souce tree then use that static library inside your project .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to watch their video so I'm guessing that the "Source Tree" method refers to the git management software, "Source Tree." (Which is really awesome free software BTW...)

A quick google search shows that you can get FastPdfKit from [the github repository](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit).

```
git clone https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit.git
```

You may want to use git "submodules" now, that's up to you.

Comment: Paul: according to apple docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-source_trees_preferences/About.html look at the note in the box in the middle of the page: source trees are not related to source control ...